# Using nested for loops to print the following values

Tags: java, nested-loops

I am getting so frustrated because I cannot figure out how to write the below code in java and make it work. Whenever I do it, my data is formatted improperly. Please help! Here is the question:

Use nested for loops to produce the following output

```
     1  1
     1  2
     1  3
     1  4
     2  1
     2  2
     2  3
     2  4
```

Let the outer loop print the numbers in the left column, and the inner loop print the numbers in the right column.  In each iteration, print the loop control variables to produce the output.

Comment: Post the code that you've written if you will.

Comment: bravo ! thanks for hekping us to understand the question. Please enlighten us by showing your code as well

Comment: Have you written any code for above requirement , please post the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= 4; j++)
       System.out.printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
       // Alternatively:
       // System.out.println(i + "  " + j);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for (int i=1; i<=2; ++i)
    for (int j=1; j<=4; ++j)
        cout << i << "  "<<j;
```

Comment: The question was tagged with `java`, but you have a `c++` solution.